# Automatically add anti-forgery tokens in ASP.NET MVC with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, razor, antiforgerytoken

To prevent Cross-site request forgery you need to add an anti-forgery token to every form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

I would like to avoid adding `@Html.AntiForgeryToken` to all forms. Is there a way to automate this process?

The German [Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site-Request-Forgery#Serverseitig) ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLLer.png)) states a hidden field with the token will be added automatically after `@Html.BeginForm`, but it looks like this is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Found a (non optimal) solution [here](https://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/adding-asp-net-mvc-anti-forgery-tokens-to-all-post-requests-easily/).

He uses another extension method to add the anti-forgery token. This has the disadvantage that you need new methods for all existing HtmlHelper extensions and the code might become inconsistent.

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static MvcForm BeginDataForm(this HtmlHelper html, string action, string controller)
    {
        var form = html.BeginForm(action, controller);

        html.ViewContext.Writer.Write(html.AntiForgeryToken().ToHtmlString());

        return form;
    }
}
```

On the server side, he found an elegant solution to validate the token. He added a new AuthorizationFilter and validates the token on every Post Method.

```
public class GlobalAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public sub OnAuthorization(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper() == "POST")
        {
            AntiForgery.Validate();
        }
    }
}
```